# My question about xpath not working on Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download files for a specific date from a website using Selenium's `xpath` like below. I'm using it to find the link I want from a website form.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(.,'10/30/2018')] and @class='Row ']//span")).click();
```

When I directly search the HTML in Chrome browser using `xpath`, it gaves me the result I want. However, if I use Selenium' `xpath` (web driver is Chrome's) in java program to locate the element, I got "No Such Element Exception". I have tried longer wait for web loading using

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But it did not work.

Could anyone tell me why?

I see that the link is located in a "iframe" tag. Is it something I should deal with first?

The web structure is basically like this

```
<tr>
  <tr class="Row ">
    <td>10/30/2018 9:00:00 PM<td>
    <td>
      <span>
        <input type="submit" value="Download"></input>
        <input type="hidden"></input>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="Row ">
    <td>10/27/2018 9:00:00 PM<td>
    <td>
      <span>
        <input type="submit" value="Download"></input>
        <input type="hidden"></input>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</tr>
```

I also tried this and did not work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[contains(.,'10/30/2018')] and @class='Row ']//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Comment: Can you show the html structure that is underlying to this question? Maybe the xpath is wrong...

Comment: I have added the structure. I thought my xpath would be right because it worked when I directly use it for search in the website

Comment: try this: `//tr/td[contains(text(),'10/30/2018') and contains(@class,'Row')]/../td/span`

Comment: Like on a website when you "Inspect Element" and "Ctrl + F" and input the xpath, and the desired element is located. It just did not work using Selenium in my java program.

Comment: The implicitWait() only waits the DOM to be loaded, but the //tr element you're looking for seems to be dynamically loaded. Did you try explicitly wait to the element using a WebDriverWait() ?

Comment: Check whether `table` located inside a frame/iframe. And note that your HTML sample is not well-formed. Please update it as well

Comment: also try to wait for element instead of finding it

Comment: I just tried WebDriverWait and it did not work.

Comment: When I used Selenium IDE to record the process, I do see a "select frame" action before "click"  when I clicked the download button on the web page

Answer (score 0):

My question is solved. The reason I cannot find the element is that it's in a iframe tag. It mean it's another website inside the current website. To handle that, I need to use switchTo function to go to that website first, then I can work on it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0));
```